# WPF TreeView with icons and text

Tags: c#, wpf

Working on learning WPF by converting my win forms apps. Currently having a hard time figuring out how to add TreeViewItems to a TreeView that contains am image before text all on the same line. My images are png files that are listed as a resource.

I want to be able to specify the image and text of each item. Everything I have been seeing are setting default images.

Would really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

See this for how to bind the image in more detail:
[Binding image source through property in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358553/binding-image-source-through-property-in-wpf)

Comment: I have actually switched this to the answer. Although I have gave points to both. After doing some reading, I think tat an ItemTemplate is the better option here.