# getting error while trying to change image source wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, imagesource

I have a **DataGrid** in my wpf window, and it's got a **ContextMenu** with items **Update** and **Delete**

When Update is Clicked the selected item's **Name**, **UserName** etc... is shown in **TextBox**es of the window, so that the user can change them (when the user clicks on a **addUserBtn** the changes are saved to database)

Now,
one of the **User**'s properties is thier **Image**, and i show that image using `Image` element in WPF. the source of the image is by default a file inside the project. but when `Update` is clicked, the `ImageSource` becomes the **User**'s **Image**'s address (gotten from database)

I've used the code below to Copy the image file into the application's executable path, and then save the file's address in the database

```html
string SavePic(string UserName)
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\UserPictures\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string picName = UserName + ".jpg";
            try
            {
                string picPath = ofd.FileName;
                File.Copy(picPath, path + picName, true); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MyMessageBox mb = new MyMessageBox("System was unable to save the picture\n" + e.Message);
                mb.ShowDialog();
            }
            return path + picName;
        }
```

So far so good

But the problem is when i try to save the changes (after clicking on `Update`ContextMenu).

Weather I change the image or not, i get an error

Let's say I only want to change the **User**'s Name, but the image is untouched, then I get this error `.Empty file name is not legal   Parameter name: sourceFileName`

And if I change the image, I get this other error => `The process cannot access the file 'C:Users`etc...`.because it is being used by another process`

Just in case, this is the code, behind `Update`ContextMenu button:

```html
flagUpdate = true;
            User temp = bll.Read(idValue);
            txtName.Text = temp.Name;
            txtUsername.Text = temp.UserName;
            if (temp.Picture != null)
            {
                ProfilePicImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(temp.Picture));
            }
            else
            {
                ProfilePicImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Image/UserWindow/UserProfileImage.png"));
            }
```

And this is the code behind `addUserBtn` which saves the new values to the database:

```html
User tempId = bll.Read(idValue);
                        User temp = new User();
                        temp.Name = txtName.Text;
                        temp.UserName = txtUsername.Text;
                        temp.Picture = SavePic(txtUsername.Text);
                        if (txtPassword.Text != "")
                        {
                            temp.Password = txtPassword.Text;
                        }
                        string action = bll.Update(temp, idValue);
                        ProfilePicImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Image/UserWindow/UserProfileImage.png"));
                        flagUpdate = false;
                        MyMessageBox mb = new MyMessageBox(action);
                        OpenWindow(mb);
                        DataGridFill();
```

it got very long :)

just wanted to give you all the information just in case, since I myself am clueless about what I should do

Comment: The reason for the error message is that BitmapImage by default keeps the source file open. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625691/1136211) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265190/1136211) for a solution. You should however avoid to "*copy the image file into the application's executable path*", because your application may not be allowed to write into that folder.

Comment: I read the answers given in the two pages you recommended
but since i'm fairly new to C# i can't quite understand what exactly i should do
can you take a look at my SavePic method and tell me how i should write the code plz?