# Powershell WPF Image.Source Changed from picture 1 to 2, but handle to picture 1 still exist

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a pure powershell script with WPF and XAML GUI. There is an Image loaded like $WPFImage.Source='C:..\1.png' when I change the Source to another picture, it shows the other picture properly. But the first picture is still locked.
Unfortunately the Image control has no Dispose method. Any idea how to close the open handle/filestream?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29625428/1136211, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12799931/1136211, not sure if you can make use of it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] Figured it out, no special XAML necessary, pure Powershell Solution:

```
$img = New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
$img.BeginInit()
$img.UriSource = "C:\temp\Screenshots\1.png"
$img.CacheOption = [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption]::OnLoad
$img.EndInit()
$img.Freeze()
$WPFimg.Source=$img
```

Thank you Clemens for comment.